# Javascript not loading correctly in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I have a messages page where i can see them as a list. If i select each one of them, I display them in the right side of the page. For that, I have two javascript functions for "next" and "previous" buttons for the messages' page. So I have a list of messages on the screen, if I click "next", I see the next page of messages and so on.
Everything work allright, the only problem is in Chrome, it wouldn't load the page number in a span section on the bottom of the page. This is the function for next page:

> ```
> $("#next").click(function() {
> ```

```
    var currentPageElem = $("#currentPage");
    var totalPagesElem = $("#totalPages");  
    var minItemElem = $("#minItem");
    var maxItemElem = $("#maxItem");
    var totalItemsElem = $("#totalItems");
    var itemsOnPageElem = $("#itemsOnPage");
    var currentPageValue = parseInt(currentPageElem.val(), 10);

    if (currentPageValue < totalPagesElem.val()) {
        currentPageElem.val(currentPageValue + 1);
    }

    //the first record on the current page
    minItem = $(this).getMinItem(currentPageElem.val(), itemsOnPageElem.val());
    minItemElem.val(minItem);

    //the last record on the current page
    maxItem = $(this).getMaxItem(currentPageElem.val(), itemsOnPageElem.val(), totalItemsElem.val());
    maxItemElem.val(maxItem);

    $(this).showItems(minItem, maxItem);

    var pageHtml = $(".pages").html();
    $(".pages").html($(this).newPageHtml(pageHtml, currentPageElem.val()));
}); });
```

> $.fn.newPageHtml = function(pageHtml, currentPage) {

```
    var idx1=pageHtml.indexOf("Pagina "); 
    var idx2=pageHtml.indexOf(" / ");
    var prevPage = pageHtml.substring(idx1 + 7, idx2);
    return pageHtml.replace(prevPage, currentPage);
};
```

This is the html code that involves the js:

```
<input type="hidden" id="totalPages" name="totalPages" value="${totalPages}"/>  
<input type="hidden" id="currentPage" name="currentPage" value="${currentPage}"/>   
<input type="hidden" id="minItem" name="minItem" value="${minItem}"/>   
<input type="hidden" id="maxItem" name="maxItem" value="${maxItem}"/>
```

...

```
<div class="controls">
        <a class="prev" id="prev"></a>
        <a class="next" id="next"></a>
        <span class="pages">
            <fmt:message key="messages.page">
                <fmt:param>${currentPage}</fmt:param>
                <fmt:param>${totalPages}</fmt:param>
            </fmt:message></span></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem. There was an issue with the CSS files that wouldn't allow the text to transform correctly in Google Chrome. So I modified the style of the span class from above like this:

`<span class="pages" style = " position: absolute; ">`

Initially, the position of the span class was relative. I think Chrome has a problem with this type of CSS.

Answer (score 0):

are you try in firefox or safari?
what is your java version?
are you review in about:config if you have enable java/javascript in Chrome

Comment: Yes, it is working ok in firefox, safari and ie. Also i have enabled javascript in chrome. Everything loads properly, it is just the text that indicates the page number that doesn't load in this browser..

Comment: have you MAC and java 7 installed?

Comment: i think i have everything i need. i don't use a MAC, though.

Comment: Ok i said because java7 in MAC for 64 bits isn't supported

Comment: the css and js jquery can put it , how are you called